# pyarrow memory consumption difference between Dataset.to_batches and ParquetFile.iter_batches

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am using `pyarrow` and am struggling to understand the big difference in memory usage between the `Dataset.to_batches` method compared to `ParquetFile.iter_batches`.

**Using pyarrow.dataset**

```py
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> import pyarrow.dataset as ds
>>>
>>> filelist = [
...     'local_data/file1.parquet'
... ]
>>> input_dataset = ds.dataset(source=filelist)
>>> sink = pa.BufferOutputStream()
>>> writer = pa.ipc.new_stream(sink, input_dataset.schema)
>>> ds_batches = input_dataset.to_batches(batch_size=500, batch_readahead=0, fragment_readahead=0)
>>> for _ in range(4):
...     writer.write_batch(next(ds_batches))
...
>>> buf = sink.getvalue()
>>> buf.size
5637392
```

Looking at memory consumption in task manager, before the line `ds_batches = input_dataset.to_batches(batch_size=500, batch_readahead=0, fragment_readahead=0)` it is around 44MB, once I execute that line it jumps to ~815MB.  This is surprising because I thought `to_batches` returns an iterator and that memory should start to be consumed only after I start iteration.  I did notice that memory remains stable even as I am iterating over batches.

**Using pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile**

```py
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> import pyarrow.parquet as pq
>>>
>>> filelist = [
...     'local_data/file1.parquet'
... ]
>>> pqfile = pq.ParquetFile(filelist[0])
>>> sink = pa.BufferOutputStream()
>>> writer = pa.ipc.new_stream(sink, pqfile.schema_arrow)
>>> pqiterator = pq.ParquetFile(filelist[0]).iter_batches(batch_size=500)
>>> for _ in range(4):
...     writer.write_batch(next(pqiterator))
...
>>> buf = sink.getvalue()
>>> buf.size
5636632
```

Behavior here is more in line with what I expected.  Memory consumption does not change once I execute `pqiterator = pq.ParquetFile(filelist[0]).iter_batches(batch_size=500)` and remains at a very low 19MB.

Note that at the end of both scenarios, the size of the buffer is around 5MB in both cases.  And if I read back out of that buffer I get the same (and expected) number of records.

- Question 1:  what explains the high memory consumption of `Dataset.to_batches`?
- Question 2:  why is there such a difference between `Dataset.to_batches` and `ParquetFile.iter_batches`, both of which basically allow me to iterate over batches of records?

**Notes:**

1. The [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.to_batches) on `to_batches` says

> Read the dataset as materialized record batches.

I wondered if "materialized" actually meant it was returning all batches, but that doesn't seem right either as all batches in the file would take up a lot more space.

2. I see the same results if I use `Dataset.scanner()` instead of `Dataset.to_batches`, even though the [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.scanner) for `scanner` says

> Data is not loaded immediately. Instead, this produces a Scanner, which exposes further operations

Comment: Were you able to find an answer? I too stumbled upon this issue yesterday, ParquetFile was being much faster (200ms vs 1.3s) than dataset approach in my case.

Comment: @Pratham unfortunately I've not yet found an answer.  Though, I've shifted to working on something else for the time being so haven't been actively looking.

Comment: My main problem here is not so much speed as lack of memory predictability.  I have data (with same schema) coming from different sources, some more densely packed than others, resulting in different memory footprints for the same batch size.  When I return to working on this, I want to figure out how to read with dynamic batch size so as to keep memory consumption below some threshold.  I will update this question if I'm able to do so.